# AngularJS directive toggle menu preventing default for other directive

Tags: events, angularjs, directive

So I made a directive for a toggle (drop down) menu in AngularJS. I used the directive for multiple items within the page but I have a small problem. When one item is open and I click another one I want the previous one to close. The event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation stops the event for the previous item and doesn't close it. Any ideas on how to fix this? Is there a way to perhaps only stop the event within the scope?

```
app.directive('toggleMenu', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'CA',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var opened = false;
            var button = (attrs.menuButton ? angular.element(document.getElementById(attrs.menuButton)) : element.parent());
            var closeButton = (attrs.closeButton ? angular.element(document.getElementById(attrs.closeButton)) : false);

            var toggleMenu = function(){
                (opened ? element.fadeOut('fast') : element.fadeIn('fast'));
            };

            button.bind('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                toggleMenu();
                opened = ! opened;
            });

            element.bind('click', function(event){
                if(attrs.stayOpen && event.target != closeButton[0]){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
            });

            $document.bind('click', function(){
                if(opened){
                    toggleMenu();
                    opened = false;
                }
            });


        }
    };
```

And here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JknUJ/5/
Button opens content and content should close when clicked outside the div. When clicked on button 2 however content 1 doesn't close.

Comment: We can has any [fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net), [plunks](http://plnkr.co/) or [pens](http://codepen.io/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea is that you need to share the state between all your dropdown submenus, so when one of them is shown, all others are hidden. The simpliest way of storing state (such as opened or closed) are... CSS classes!

We'll create a pair of directives - one for menu, and another for sumbenu. It is more expressive that just `div`s.

Here is out markup.

```
<menu>
  <submenu data-caption="Button 1">
    Content 1
  </submenu>
  <submenu data-caption="Button 2">
    Content 2
  </submenu>
</menu>
```

Look how readable is it! Say thanks to directives:

```
plunker.directive("menu", function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {},
        transclude : true,
        replace : true,
        template : "<div class='menu' data-ng-transclude></div>",
        controller : function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude){
            $scope.submenus = [];

            this.addSubmenu = function (submenu) {
                $scope.submenus.push(submenu);
            }

            this.closeAllSubmenus = function (doNotTouch){
                angular.forEach($scope.submenus, function(submenu){
                    if(submenu != doNotTouch){
                        submenu.close();    
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
});

plunker.directive("submenu", function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        require : "^menu",
        scope : {
            caption : "@"
        },
        transclude : true,
        replace : true,
        template : "<div class='submenu'><label>{{caption}}</label><div class='submenu-content' data-ng-transclude></div></div>",
        link : function ($scope, $iElement, $iAttrs, menuController) {
            menuController.addSubmenu($scope);

            $iElement.bind("click", function(event){
                menuController.closeAllSubmenus($scope);
                $iElement.toggleClass("active");
            });

            $scope.close = function (){
                $iElement.removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Look thar we restricted them to HTML elements (`restrict : "E"`). `submenu` requires to be nested in `menu` (`require : "^menu"`), this allows us to inject menu controller to `submenu`'s link function. `transclude` and `replace` controls the position of original markup in compiled HTML output (`replace=true` means that original markup will be replaced with compiled, `transclude` inserts parts of original markup to compiled output).

When we've done with this, we just say to menu *close all your child menus!* and menu iterates over submenus, forcing them to close.

We are adding childs to `menu` controller in `addSubmenu` function. It is called in `submenu`s link function, thus every compiled instance of submenu adds itself to `menu`. Now, closing all `submenus` is as easy as iterating over all children, this is done by `closeAllSubmenus` in `menu` controller.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yttY9PrZBdgeUZfQXXMx) is a full Plunker to play with.