# Angularjs: please confirm if the $document.bind function can be omitted in this directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Can someone please confirm if the $document.bind function can be omitted in the link function below? It seems to have no consequence on the actual code behaviour but since I still struggle with any code intended to manipulate the Dom, I'd appreciate if someone can explain $document's role here if any. Here is [my working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/CCe3x/1/) with some refactoring and params commented out as they do not seem used. Here is a link to the [original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171901/angularjs-directive-toggle-menu-preventing-default-for-other-directive).

Also I am in doubt as to whether there is a better way to gain skills on Dom manipulation that doesn't involve learning jquery. I've considered just reviewing the w3 schools lessons on Jquery :-). There are not too many examples found on the Angular docs showing how to use the jquerylite api which is certainly challenging in terms of understanding how its to be used without these skills. Is learning jquery the way to go or is there a better route?

```
            link: function ($scope, $iElement, $iAttrs, menuController) {
                menuController.addSubmenu($scope);

                $iElement.bind("click", function (event) {
                     menuController.closeAllOtherToggableContent($scope);
                     event.preventDefault();
                     event.stopPropagation();
                     $iElement.toggleClass("active");
            });

            $scope.close = function () {
                     $iElement.removeClass("active");
            };

            $document.bind("click", function () {
       //
       //         menuController.closeAllOtherToggableContent();
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I uncomment this part of your directive:

```
$document.bind("click", function () {
        menuController.closeAllOtherToggableContent();
})
```

It does a "click away" event, meaning it's closing all open menus on click away of your buttons. If this is what you intend, then yes you need this.

With regards to DOM manipulation skills- review and learn all of what you mention. W3C schools is good start.

Comment: Indeed it does. Thx Koolunix manipulating the Dom is easy when u learn the basics :-)